# Let P be a point inside an equilateral $△ABC, PA=5, PB=12, PC=13$. What is the ratio in which P divides the 3 sections of the triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

We can find the edge length of the triangle, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758901/edge-length-of-an-equilateral-triangle-if-distances-from-a-point-p-to-its-vert#:%7E:text=A%20point%20P%20is%20located,%2B60%E2%88%9A(3).&text=So%2C%20cosx%3D%E2%88%92s,%E2%88%92s2%E2%88%92313312) thread.

My approach for the triplets are to find a $90° + 60°$ i.e. see $△XPB$ ,
 $∠XPB = 90$ & $∠APX = 60°$.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjgt0.png)

Followed by using the cosine formula in $△APB$ , i.e. $AB = \sqrt{AP^2 + PB^2 - 2AP⋅PB⋅cos(∠APB)}$

But then I got stuck...

Also I would like to generalize this for any Pythagorean Triplet.

Comment: Using rotation, you can show that in general, $\angle PAB = 150^0$ if $PA^2+PB^2 = PC^2$ and $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, that is what I had done. But I'm still not getting any leads to find areas...

Comment: Did you find the side length of the equilateral triangle? If yes, then you know all 3 sides of triangles. So we can find their areas using Heron's formula, right?